# Problem installing Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

This is my first attempt to install Ubuntu Touch.
I've run

```
phablet-flash cdimage-touch -d mako -b
```

and it goes all the way through to

```
INFO:phablet-flash:Flashing system to /home/ham/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130808/saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+mako.img
< waiting for device >
```

where it just hangs.  The phone has rebooted into the screen with the Android on its back and the big green arrow 'Start', but it's just sitting there and nothing appears to be happening: the phone is just staring at me with the big green arrow and my Ubuntu 12.10 desktop is staring at me with the above '< waiting for device >'.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this too on Maguro.
Use the volume rocker to change 'start' into recovery than press powerbutton.
Leave the cable attached.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working.  I get the recovery screen (the little android on its back, spilling its guts) but I see the words 'No Command' beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

You sure the device was oem unlocked and cache cleaned and all?
You might want to start from the beginning of the manual again.
If you reboot it, does it have recovery?

Comment: I gave up.  I've flashed CM Recovery + SuperSU and then installed the two .zip Ubuntu Touch files manually.  Thanks for your help anyways.